# Why is my Global Boolean always resulting in false?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

So I'm trying to use a global boolean variable in C++, but it's always returning false.  I define the value in my mainmenuscene.h file:

```
#ifndef MAINMENUSCENE_H_
#define MAINMENUSCENE_H_
#include "cocos2d.h"

extern bool boo_startgame;


class MainMenu : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{....}
```

In my mainmenuscene.cpp file, I set it to true:

```
void MainMenu::menuStartSinglePlayer(CCObject* pSender)
{
    boo_startgame=true;
    CCDirector *pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    pDirector->setOpenGLView(CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView());

    // create a scene. it's an autorelease object
    CCScene *pScene = HelloWorld::scene();

    // run
    pDirector->pushScene(pScene);
}
```

But in my helloworldscene.cpp file, it's set back to false.

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
bool boo_startgame;

bool HelloWorld::init()
        {
               CCLog(boo_startgame ? "boo_startgame=true" : "boo_startgame=false");
               if (boo_startgame==true)
                   {
                     int_dealer=(arc4random() % 4);
                   }
    ....}
```

For whatever reason, the portion inside the if statement never fires, so I know it isn't my CCLog code messing up.  What's going on here?

Comment: How do we know that `menuStartSinglePlayer` is being called before `init`?  Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: You aren't including `mainmenuscene.h` in `helloworldscene.cpp`. Who knows whether it's the same one?

Comment: @chris: That's not strictly necessary (although definitely a good idea in general).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, Interesting, I guess there's no way to shadow it then?

Comment: I have the mainmenuscene.h file included in my helloworldscene.h file.

Comment: @chris: Indeed.  If there were an identically-named variable *defined* in multiple translation units, there'd be a linker error.

Comment: And yes, we know that menuStartSinglePlayer is called before the helloworld init, because it's a button that launches the helloworldscene.

Comment: @PWiggin: Ok.  But there's not evidence here to allow an explanation.  For all we know, there's some other piece of code that you haven't shown that's resetting it, or maybe you have some undefined behaviour somewhere which is trashing the variable.

Comment: Oli, please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.  My global definition of boo_startgame was defined correctly, but I also had it defined as a classwide inside my helloworld.h file.  I thought I would get a linker error if I did something like that, but apparently not.

Answer (score -1):

You might try declaring your boolean as `volatile bool boo_startgame` if it can be modified in one thread of execution and tested in another.